# How do I use a boolean operation on individual instances in a geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: geometry nodes]

Naïvely, one would attempt to do something like this, but this yields counterintuitively intuitive results: instead of applying the boolean individually to every instance, it applies the boolean as if each instance were its own mesh. The result of the boolean operation is the area where *every instance* intersects with every other instance *as well as* the input mesh (i.e. nowhere).

[image: successful boolean]

Desired results can seemingly be obtained if a Realize Instances node is added after instancing the objects, but this is a destructive operation and instance indices/positions can no longer be used for further processing.

Comment: is this your desired result what you are showing in the image?

Comment: By essence and for optimization purposes instances share the same base mesh data, so what you're trying to do without first realizing the instances, is impossible I think.

Comment: It would seem as though the Mesh Boolean operation implicitly realizes instances anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instances are the same mesh on different positions. It's like then you duplicate linked <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - if you edit one instance - all others edits in the same time, because they share the same data. So it is impossible to make boolean this way, you can bool one instance all others will get the same data.

Then you use **Realize Instances**, instances convert into one big mesh. But it's wrong that they lose instance data.

Take a look in example (Blender should be at least 3.1 version):

[image]

You can access to Instance index using **capture attribute** and pass it into recently created points using **transfer attribute**